# Pandas - Applying formula on all column based on a value on the row

Tags: python, pandas

lets say I have a dataframe like below

```
+------+------+------+-------------+
|  A   |   B  |  C   | devisor_col |
+------+------+------+-------------+
|    2 |    4 |   10 |           2 |
|    3 |    3 |    9 |           3 |
|   10 |   25 |   40 |          10 |
+------+------+------+-------------+
```

what would be the best command to apply a formula using values from the devisor_col. Do note that I have thousand of column and rows.

the result should be like this:

```
+------+------+------+-------------+
| A    | B    | V    | devisor_col |
+------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 |    2 |    5 |           2 |
|    1 |    1 |    3 |           3 |
|    1 |  1.5 |    4 |          10 |
+------+------+------+-------------+
```

I tried using apply map but I dont know why I cant apply it to all columns.

```
modResult = my_df.applymap(lambda x: x/x["devisor_col"]))
```

Comment: did you try `df['Col1'] = df['Col1']/df['devisor_col']`?

Comment: I need to apply it on multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use [`pandas.DataFrame.divide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html) on `axis=0` :

```
modResult= (
        pd.concat(
            [my_df, my_df.filter(like="Col") # selecting columns
                   .divide(my_df["devisor_col"], axis=0).add_suffix("_div")], axis=1)
           )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(modResult)

   Col1  Col2  Col3  devisor_col  Col1_div  Col2_div  Col3_div
0     2     4    10            2       1.0       2.0       5.0
1     3     3     9            3       1.0       1.0       3.0
2    10    25    40           10       1.0       2.5       4.0
```

If you need only the result of the divide, use this :

```
modResult= my_df.filter(like="Col").divide(my_df["devisor_col"], axis=0)

print(modResult)

   Col1  Col2  Col3
0   1.0   2.0   5.0
1   1.0   1.0   3.0
2   1.0   2.5   4.0
```

Or if you want to overwrite the old columns, use [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
modResult= (
            my_df.filter(like="Col")
                 .divide(my_df["devisor_col"], axis=0)
                 .join(my_df["devisor_col"])
           )

   Col1  Col2  Col3  devisor_col
0   1.0   2.0   5.0            2
1   1.0   1.0   3.0            3
2   1.0   2.5   4.0           10
```

You can replace `my_df.filter(like="Col")` with `my_df.loc[:, my_df.columns!="devisor_col"]`.

Comment: and what if the column names were different

Comment: Use `.loc` as mentionned at the end of my answer.

Comment: Now it is good.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `.loc`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,1],[2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7]], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'divisor'])

df.loc[:, df.columns != 'divisor'] = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'divisor'].divide(df['divisor'], axis=0)
```